# The position and potential energy of the masses in two mass rigid body pendulum lie on a cirlce

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

Suppose I have  two mass rigid pendulum, both of whose masses
are equidistant from the pivot point at P. All three points lie on a circle of diamater D and subtend an angle $\alpha$ at the pivot. let the distance of each mass from the pivot point be $\ell$

**My questions is:**

**1.** why is it true that at equilibirium, the position of the masses (**below the point P**) is $$l \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \alpha\right)=l^{2} / D$$ I understand the leftside of the equation but do not understand why is it equal to right side, in other words why $$ \ cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \alpha\right)=l / D$$

**2.**  why the gravitational potential energy of the system, after being displaced over a small angle $\theta$ is $$U \approx M g \frac{l^{2}}{D} \frac{\theta^{2}}{2}$$ I am having hard time to understand the math behind those two questions

Comment: What do you mean by equilibrium?  Are these masses moving in a circle? Are there forces other than tension and gravity? Exactly what is rigid?

Comment: The masses lies on the circle, no other force exept gravity and tension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1 is simply a consequence of the geometry of the scenario, and has nothing to do with its dynamics. If you draw a line from one mass (at, say, $A$) to the centre of the circle at $O$ then $OAP$ is an isosceles triangle with side $\frac D 2, \frac D 2, l$ and acute angle $\frac \alpha 2$. It follows that

$\displaystyle \cos \left( \frac \alpha 2 \right) = \frac l D$

For part 2, if we assume *both* masses move through a small angle $\theta$ then the change in PE is

$\displaystyle Mgl \left( \cos \left(  \frac \alpha 2 \right) - \cos \left( \frac \alpha 2 + \theta \right) \right)
\approx Mgl \cos \left( \frac \alpha 2 \right) \frac {\theta^2}{2} $

Comment: I'm srry mate but I can't understand what you mean by explaining part 1, I tried to draw what you mentioned but AP should be equal to $\ell$ from the given and also  I still not understand how the cosine of alpha is $\frac{l}{D}$ if AP is the hyper. 
About part 2, I still don't understand this approximation $\displaystyle Mgl \left( \cos \left(  \frac \alpha 2 \right) - \cos \left( \frac \alpha 2 + \theta \right) \right)
\approx Mgl \cos \left( \frac \alpha 2 \right) \frac {\theta^2}{2}$ what the math tool you used? tylor expansion?

Comment: @Sagigever I have corrected my answer. The short sides of the triangle are length $\frac D 2$, the long side $AP$ is length $l$, and the cosine of $\frac \alpha 2$ is half the long side divided by the short side, so $\frac l D$. For part 2, yes, use Taylor expansion of $\cos \theta$ since $\theta$ is small.

Comment: I do not understand how I should get this approximation in part 2, I know that in small angles I can write $cos(\theta) \approx 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2}$ but how do I use it here? should I use a trigonometric identities? If you can show me the method I will be really gratitude

Comment: @Sagigever I wrote you the answer for this

Answer (score 1):

I have this answer for you:

[image]

**Point I:**

I use the $\pi/2$ angle those:

$$D\,\cos(\alpha/2)=l$$

**Point II:**

The total Potential Energy is:

$$U=-M\,g\,l\cos(\varphi+\alpha/2)\tag 1$$

obtain the Taylor series for  $\varphi\mapsto \Delta\varphi$

$$U\approx M\,g\,l\,\left(-\cos \left( 1/2\,\alpha \right) +\sin \left( 1/2\,\alpha \right) 
\Delta \varphi +1/2\,\cos \left( 1/2\,\alpha \right) {\Delta \varphi }
^{2}
\right) $$

with $\alpha=2\,\arccos \left( {\frac {l}{D}} \right)$ you obtain:

$$U\approx M\,g\,l\,\left(\underbrace{-{\frac {l}{D}}+{\frac {\sqrt {{D}^{2}-{l}^{2}}\Delta \varphi }{D}}}_{U_\varphi}+\frac 12\,{\frac {l{\Delta \varphi }^{2}}{D}}\right)
$$

because the force $F_\varphi=\frac{\partial U_\varphi}{\partial \Delta \varphi}$ is constant  we can neglecting  this part.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed solution, can you explain why the fatct that $F_\varphi=\frac{\partial U_\varphi}{\partial \Delta \varphi}$ is constant allow us to neglect this part?

Comment: This is because we are looking for a solution where the pendulum is in static equilibrium state.

Comment: I am still not understanding your argue, in equilibiruim $F_{\phi}= 0$ if i understand it correctly

Comment: If you generate the equation of motion you see that  $\phi(0)$ Is the acceleration not zero ,due to a constant force,you don’t have static equilibrium.